# Sorting a property in flask-admin list view

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a model with a date of birth field, I have used the python decorator @property to make an age field, I would like to be able to sort by age on the flask-admin list view but I got the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'property'> instead
```

This is how I am doing it:

```
class User(db.model, UserMixin):
...
data_de_nascimento = db.Column(db.Date)
...
@property
def idade(self):
    today = date.today()
    born = self.data_de_nascimento
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
```

I have tried to change the @property for the SQLAlchemy @hybrid_property but I am not sure if this is the correct approach since I don't really understand it. Still, I got the following error: ( I tried reading the docs but did not make much sense of them)

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with User.data_de_nascimento has an attribute 'year'
```

I am not sure how to go about this, can someone point me to a simple working solution?

My first idea was to save age directly on the database but I don't know how to update it every time a user has a birthday.

I also think it would work if I could change the query generated by Flask-admin and just sort by the DOB instead of the age but I have not found a way to do it.